# Probability of selecting red balls from blue balls

Tags: probability

Given that the probability of selecting a red ball is $p$, what is the probability of selecting $1$ red ball/ $x$ red balls from $n$ red balls and $m$ blue balls?

How do we do a question like this?

What I mean when I say the probability of selecting a red ball is $p$, I mean that there is some bias toward selecting a red ball independent of the number of red and blue balls.

Comment: Um... All balls are red so $100%$ no matter what...? Is there a typo?

Comment: Sorry, fixed it

Comment: I think we need to specify the question a bit more. How many balls are drawn, how are they drawn, what is the condition we are looking for?